# $\int_{\Omega} f \psi = 0$ for every $\psi$ which is zero at $\partial \Omega$ imples $f=0$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is a generalization of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005784/does-int-iftgtdt-0-for-every-g-partial-i-0-implies-f-equiv-0). Let $I=[t_{0},t_{1}]\subset \mathbb{R}$ be fixed and  $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\psi$ and $f$ be sufficiently differentiable (we can assume it to be smooth) and let us assume that $\psi(t_{0},x)= \psi(t_{1},x) = 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\psi(t,x)|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$ for every $t \in I$. If:
$$\int_{I}\int_{\Omega}f(t,x)\psi(t,x)dxdt = 0$$
for **every** $\psi$ satisfying the above conditions, is it true that $f(t,x) \equiv 0$?

Comment: What kind of restrictions are you okay with making on $\Omega$? Is it open, closed, compact? Typically talking about differentiability, one assumes the domain to be open (to make differentiability theorems apply), or the closure of an open set, though it is not clear from your question whether the *point* of the question is that $I$ is closed and $\Omega$ may not be.

Comment: This problem arose from a physics problem and $\Omega$ is there just to make the integrals well-defined. In particular, the integral in the original problem must be zero for every $\Omega$. I believe $\Omega$ should be compact with piecewise smooth $\partial\Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider just those $\psi(t,x) = \phi(t)g(x)$.
$$
0=\int_I \int_\Omega f(t,x)\psi(t,x)\,dx\,dt = \int_I \phi(t) \left(\int_\Omega f(t,x)g(x)\,dx\right)\,dt = \int_I \phi(t) F_g(t)\,dt.
$$
where $F_g$ is the inner integral.
The assumptions imply (e.g. by your previous question) that $F_g(t) = 0$ for all $t \in I$.
Fix $t \in I$ and let $f_t(x) := f(t,x)$.
Since $g$ (smooth enough etc.)  was unrestrained, we have
$$
0 = \int_\Omega f_t(x) g(x)\,dx
$$
for all smooth $g$.
Assume for sake of contradiction that $f_t(x_0) \neq 0$ for some $x_0$ on the interior of $\Omega$.
Take $g$ to be a positive smooth approximation of $1_{B(x_0)}$ where $B(x_0)$ is a ball around an arbitrary point $x_0$ such that $B(x_0) \subseteq \Omega$ and $f$ does not change sign in $B(x_0)$. Then we find that $\int_{B(x_0)}f_t(x) g(x) \, dx = 0$ but the integral of a smooth function of constant sign being zero means the function is zero, so we arrive at a contradiction, $f_t(x_0)$ must be $0$.
Hence $f_t(x_0) = 0$ for all $t \in I$ and all $x$ on the interior of $\Omega$.
Since for each $t$, $f_t$ is smooth, its value on the boundary of $\Omega$ is the limit of its values on the interior (here is where we assume $\Omega$ is not a pathological set), and hence $f_t(x) =0$ for all $t \in I, x \in \Omega$.